# Dockers call by http request

Tags: docker, ubuntu, httprequest

i'm new of docker's world. I'm trying to import two Dockers model downloaded from peltarion on Ubuntu version 20.04.
I download docker, setup the two images and create the first container with command

**docker run -p 8000:8000 model-export**

when i call xxx.xx.xx.xx:8000 with http request i receive answer by it.
My problem is that when i create the second container

**docker run -p 8090:8090 model-export**

I get the following configuration on the port

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeyXR.jpg)

At this point i try to call with xxx.xx.xx.xx:8090, but no response.

How can i configure the container so i can call it with http request?
Thanks in advance to anyone who helps me

Comment: Is the container listening to port 8090 internally? If not that should probably be `-p 8090:8000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR:** your parameter values should be `-p 8090:8000`.

---

The order of `-p`/`--publish` parameter values should be:

```
published_port:container_exposed_port
```

- `published_port` is a port used by host (your machine), where Docker is installed. And that can be used outside like a public-available service. For example it can be visible by other computers in your local network, or by Internet.
- `container_exposed_port` is a port that is exposed from Docker container to Docker host by image (for example by `EXPOSE 8000` instruction in image `Dockerfile`). It's visible only for your Docker host, or for other Docker containers ([Docker networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/)) too.